# PSQL request too slow. How to fix it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datatable, count, subquery

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(a)/COUNT(s)*100 as aratio, 
    COUNT(b)/COUNT(s)*100 as bratio, 
    COUNT(c)/COUNT(s)*100 as cratio, 
    COUNT(a), 
    COUNT(b), 
    COUNT(c), 
    COUNT(s) 
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(cid) as a FROM images WHERE width > height AND category_id = 4 GROUP BY cid) as aq, 
    (SELECT COUNT(cid) as b FROM images WHERE width < height AND category_id = 4 GROUP BY cid) as bq, 
    (SELECT COUNT(cid) as c FROM images WHERE width = height AND category_id = 4 GROUP BY cid) as cq, 
    (SELECT COUNT(cid) as s FROM images WHERE category_id = 4 GROUP BY cid) as sq;
```

How can i make this request more effective?

Comment: Are you sure you need cartesian product?

Comment: nop, i do not like it, but i can't solve this problem in better way.

Comment: split to different queries and/or move to stored procedure?

Comment: no way, i need in in one request. don't tell me it's impossible :D

Comment: it is possible with using `WITH`. Move all queries to `WITH` and modify them a little: change `COUNT(cid)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT cid)` and remove `GROUP BY` clause at all.

Comment: repeated it as an answer. If it helped you - I'd be appreciated if you check it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible with using `WITH`. Move all queries to `WITH` and modify them a little: change `COUNT(cid)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT cid)` and remove `GROUP BY` clause at all.

Comment: Sometimes `GROUP BY` works faster than `DISTINCT`; worth checking before the rewrite.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus: irrelevant in this particular case. `GROUP BY` will return N rows with unique values, while `COUNT(DISTINCT cid)` will return one row with unique values count.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE (width > height) WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::float8*100/COUNT(*) as aratio, 
    SUM(CASE (width < height) WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::float8*100/COUNT(*) as bratio, 
    SUM(CASE (width = height) WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::float8*100/COUNT(*) as cratio, 
    SUM(CASE (width > height) WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
    SUM(CASE (width < height) WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
    SUM(CASE (width = height) WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    images WHERE category_id = 4;
```

this query doesn't grouping by cid, but probably you don't need it.